# Where to put precompiled pip libraries on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, pypi

I'm trying to run a Python script on Windows, but it requires some external libraries I failed to install with both pip and easy_install. I've created a virtual environment and I tried to download them from the PyPI website, but I don't know where to put what in order for them to be used in my script.

I know I should fix my installation, but I think this question can be useful even if one wants to simply get a library from it's website and manually install it, for example because he doesn't have internet connection but somehow manages to get his hands on the library file.

Example error:
[image]

Comment: You don't put them anywhere, pip does it for you. In what way did pip fail?

Comment: how are the libraries distributed? In what format? How exactly did you try to install them? What are the errors?

Comment: Inside the extracted tar there's a folder called `library_name-x.x`, inside of which a `library_name` folder, a `PKG-INFO` file and a `setup.py` file. Inside `library_name` there's a `_library_name.c` file, a `__init__.py` and a `test_library_name.py` file.

Comment: @roganjosh It gives me a `failed building wheel for library_name` error.

Comment: @EärendilBaggins copy the complete error message the `pip install` command prints and add it to the question. This is the real issue you have to solve, instead of trying to fiddle with libraries yourself.

Comment: @hoefling Added error message to question, any insight into solving this type of issue?

Comment: @jlo you need to build the [relic-toolkit](https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic) lib first and include the headers on compilation/lib files on linking.

Comment: @jlo however, if you would use 64bit Python instead of 32bit one, you wouldn't need to build anything yourself since `blspy` wheels are precompiled for the 64 bit Python.

Comment: @hoefling I've built relic-toolkit (cmake . and cmake --build .). How do I go about 'including the headers on compilation/lib files on linking'? I have a lib/Debug/ folder with relic.dll, relic.ilk, relic_s.lib, relic.pdb, relic_s.pdb. Is it related to these files?